# How to prevent falling mobs stopping my collection minecart in its tracks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built a mob farm, and the collection basin looks like this:

[image]

Usually, I have the minecart running around and collecting the items that fall. The items are then collected by the hoppers under the track (they are kinda hard to see). However, I've noticed that the cart is being stopped right in its tracks. After looking there for a while, I discovered that a mob falls and happens to be right in front of the cart, and stops it! Is there any way I can prevent this? Maybe using a chest minecart instead of a hopper minecart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an odd collection method and there are more efficient methods/setups, but if you're using hopper minecarts, you can place bottom half slabs above the rails, so the mobs die on there, and their loot can still be picked up by the hopper minecart when it passes above.

Comment: In fact, hopper minecarts, unlike regular hoppers, can also collect items through full blocks. Slabs are an ever-so-slightly more certain kill in terms of fall damage, however.